# Average every Nth column in data frame by group in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame list. I to average every n days in each df.

I am trying to `lapply` over my list.

```
test<-lapply(dataframe_list, function(d){ 
  n <- 14
  aggregate(d,list(rep(1:(nrow(d)%/%n+1),each=n,len=nrow(d))),mean)[-1]
  d
            } 
            )
```

But I get warnings:

Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(X[[1L]], ...) :
argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(X[[2L]], ...) :
argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
3: In mean.default(X[[3L]], ...) :
argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Here is the result of head(df) on one of the df in the list:

```
KGID 3MEHIS ACE_POT ADD_SUG_AVAIL_CHO ADD_SUG_TOT_SUG   ALA ALCOHOL PROTEIN_AN
1 KGID      0       0             3.135               0 1.848       0     24.181
2 KGID      0       0             3.135               0 1.848       0     24.181
3 KGID      0       0             3.135               0 1.848       0     24.181
4 KGID      0       0             3.135               0 1.848       0     24.181
5 KGID      0       0             3.135               0 1.848       0     24.181
6 KGID      0       0             3.135               0 1.848       0     24.181
```

Ultimately, I would like to see an average for the first 14 rows for this df, of course, the first column can't have an average. Is that my problem?

Comment: Please show a small example dataset 5-10 columns with 5-10 rows and expected result based on that.  The description is confusing.  For guidelines, check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Right now I have a list of dataframes. 
I am trying to lapply over the dataframe_list with a function that averages every 14 rows together for each dataframe in the list, and then call that new dataframe list "test".

`test<-lapply(dataframe_list, function(d){ 

  n <- 14

  aggregate(d,list(rep(1:(nrow(d)%/%n+1),each=n,len=nrow(d))),mean)[-1]

  d
            } 
            )`

Comment: That is fine.  But, can you show the example of a single dataset with 5-10 columns and 10 rows and its expected output, so that we can extend it to the list

Comment: What is the problem with that code?

Comment: The problem is that the code throws warnings. 

'Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(X[[1L]], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(X[[2L]], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
3: In mean.default(X[[3L]], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA'

at least 50 of them.

Here is the result of head(df):

Comment: I have updated the original post.

Comment: I posted a solution.  Please check if that works

Comment: BTW, In your example, there are character columns.  So that may be the reason you have warnings.  Subset the numeric columns and then do the mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning message suggest that you included non-numeric columns in the `mean` calculation.  In the example showed, it is the first column that is non-numeric.  We can remove the first column by `d1[-1]` and then create a new grouping column ('grp') and use the formula method in `aggregate` to get the 'mean'.  Generally, if there are many non-numeric columns, we can create a logical condition (`sapply(d1, is.numeric)`) to subset the dataset with only numeric columns.

```
 n <- 14
 aggregate(.~grp, transform(d1[sapply(d1, is.numeric)],
       grp= as.numeric(gl(nrow(d1), n, nrow(d1)))), 
              FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE, na.action=NULL)
 #   grp X3MEHIS ACE_POT ADD_SUG_AVAIL_CHO ADD_SUG_TOT_SUG   ALA ALCOHOL
 #1   1       0       0             3.135               0 1.848       0
 #  PROTEIN_AN
 #1     24.181
```

and for the list of dataframes, we can loop the same code with `lapply`.

```
 lapply(dataframe_list, function(d) aggregate(.~grp, 
       transform(d[sapply(d, is.numeric)],
            grp= as.numeric(gl(nrow(d), n, nrow(d)))),
              FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE, na.action=NULL))
```

Comment: This solution provided the output I was looking for. Thank you akrun.